# Circular patch on dog's back; ruled out mange, ringworm, other fungal causes, hotspot

Tags: dogs, health, grooming, skin-condition

I'm fostering a 5 year old rat terrier and he has a flaky bald patch.

This is an isolated patch; his skin and coat are otherwise healthy: no dandruff, fleas, mites, etc. He doesn't seem to notice it, he doesn't lick or chew it so it's not caused by him irritating the area. It's not inflamed or infected, it just constantly flakes skin.

Since it's not causing him any distress, I'm mostly asking this question so that I can find a way to stop the skin flaking before we take him to adoption events. I also want to make sure it's not a sign of something more serious.

[image: here's the little guy]

Edit: He was tested at the vet and it's not mange. He's since been moved to a foster in a different region that has more people interested in adopting, so I won't be able to follow up anymore unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried anti-fungal treatments?

Comment: Have you already taken him to the vet?

Comment: Possiby [Demodectic Mange](http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/rat-terrier#/slide/1): **take him to a vet**

Comment: I applied clotrimazole for a while because I thought it was ringworm at first. Unfortunately it made no difference. He went to the vet with the rescue agency before he got his foster placement at my house, but that was for vaccinations, etc, so I'm not sure if they looked into it there. I'm going to take him in soon because today he developed a red spot on his belly so it looks like it's less of an isolated patch than I thought, possibly. I'll post an update when I know! Thanks